# React Js: How to reload the initial data loaded via ajax?

Tags: reactjs

I get my initial data from an outside JSON in

```
componentDidMount: function() { .... $.get(jsonfile, function(data) { ....
```

But the state of "jsonfile" changes via an input.
When the state of "jsonfile" prop changes the render method is invoked again, but I will also want to re-run the `$.get` request.
What would be the proper (`react`) way to do it?

Comment: please show some code examples of your component, your question is too broad as it currently stands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should abstract away your data fetching. If you put your fetching of data in a separate helper method you can call that method when needed, and it should do the fetching (and later updating) of the state

```
React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },

    fetchData: function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.get('....', function (result) {
            _this.setState(result);
        });
    },

    handleClick: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>{data}</div>);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you tak3r, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Please do upload some code from your project if you can.

From what I understand, you are calling an API to produce a JSON response and you have a user input to the same json?

In that case if you want to make supplementary calls to the API, you should place your API call in the correct Lifecycle Methods provided by a react component.

Please see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html